# How to increase the speed of a motor when the joystick is move in the forward position.(first robotics blocks/java)

Tags: java, robotics

I am in FIRST ROBOTICS and trying to get the motors on my robots to move faster than they currently are. At the moment, the wheels move fairly slow and we want them to move faster by increasing the motor speed based on the positive and negative position of the stick.

Here is our original code, which works but does not move faster:
`

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;

@TeleOp(name = "v221 (Blocks to Java)")
public class v221 extends LinearOpMode {

  private DcMotor Back_Right;
  private DcMotor Back_Left;
  private DcMotor Front_Right;
  private DcMotor Front_Left;

  /**
   * This function is executed when this Op Mode is selected from the Driver Station.
   */
  @Override
  public void runOpMode() {
    float Back_Right2;
    float Back_Left2;
    float Front_Right2;
    float Front_Left2;

    Back_Right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Back_Right");
    Back_Left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Back_Left");
    Front_Right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Front_Right");
    Front_Left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Front_Left");

    // put initizalion blocks here
    waitForStart();
    if (opModeIsActive()) {
      // Put run blocks here.
      while (opModeIsActive()) {
        // Put loop blocks here.
        Back_Right2 = gamepad1.right_stick_y;
        Back_Right.setPower(Back_Right2);
        telemetry.addData("rightWheelpwr", Back_Right2);
        Back_Left2 = -gamepad1.left_stick_y;
        Back_Left.setPower(Back_Left2);
        telemetry.addData("leftWheelpwr", Back_Left2);
        Front_Right2 = -gamepad1.right_stick_y;
        Front_Right.setPower(Front_Right2);
        telemetry.addData("rightWheelpwr", Front_Right2);
        Front_Left2 = -gamepad1.left_stick_y;
        Front_Left.setPower(Front_Left2);
        telemetry.addData("leftWheelpwr", Front_Left2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code we made to try and make it faster:

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.TeleOp;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;

@TeleOp(name = "v2215 (Blocks to Java)")
public class v2215 extends LinearOpMode {

  private DcMotor Back_Right;
  private DcMotor Back_Left;
  private DcMotor Front_Right;
  private DcMotor Front_Left;

  /**
   * This function is executed when this Op Mode is selected from the Driver Station.
   */
  @Override
  public void runOpMode() {
    float Back_Right2;
    float Back_Left2;
    float Front_Right2;
    float Front_Left2;

    Back_Right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Back_Right");
    Back_Left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Back_Left");
    Front_Right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Front_Right");
    Front_Left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "Front_Left");

    // put initizalion blocks here
    waitForStart();
    if (opModeIsActive()) {
      // Put run blocks here.
      while (opModeIsActive()) {
        // Put loop blocks here.
        Back_Right2 = gamepad1.right_stick_y;
        Back_Right.setPower(Back_Right2);
        telemetry.addData("rightWheelpwr", Back_Right2 * 5);
        Back_Left2 = -gamepad1.left_stick_y;
        Back_Left.setPower(Back_Left2);
        telemetry.addData("leftWheelpwr", Back_Left2);
        Front_Right2 = -gamepad1.right_stick_y;
        Front_Right.setPower(Front_Right2);
        telemetry.addData("rightWheelpwr", Front_Right2);
        Front_Left2 = -gamepad1.left_stick_y;
        Front_Left.setPower(Front_Left2);
        telemetry.addData("leftWheelpwr", Front_Left2);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you know how to make it faster, please let us know.

Multiplying the power input to the motor by adding a multiplier - Expected it to multiply how far you pushed the stick by the power given to the motor.

We did more of course, but can't think of them to add

Comment: What you need to know is: First: what range of numbers do you get from the stick -- what value is `Back_Right2` when it is pushed forward? Second: what range of numbers can you give to the motor? What value makes it run at maximum speed? Then you can pass `setPower` that maximum speed number when the stick is forward.

Comment: And the Javadoc for `setPower` tells us that the maximum value is `1.0`: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.firstinspires.ftc/RobotCore/latest/com/qualcomm/robotcore/hardware/DcMotorSimple.html#setPower(double)

Comment: Maybe just a typo but your `* 5` was done just for the telemetry and not the power.